# KeyError when performing naive bayes and decision trees classification

Tags: python, decision-tree, naivebayes, keyerror

I want to classify the iris dataset using naive bayes and decision trees. I'm getting a `keyerror` that I don't understand and couldn't solve.

```
from sklearn import datasets, naive_bayes, tree, metrics
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import warnings
import random

# Get raw data and labels from the iris dataset
labelled_data = list(zip(iris_df, iris.target))

def sample_data(training_frac=0.5, iris_data=iris_df, iris_labels=iris.target):
    # separate data into training and testing sets
    training_size = int(training_frac * len(iris_data))
    
    training_idx = random.sample(range(0, len(iris_data)), k=training_size)
    testing_idx = [idx for idx in range(0, len(iris_data)) if idx not in training_idx]
    
    assert(len(training_idx) + len(testing_idx) == len(iris_data))
    
    training_set = [iris_data[idx] for idx in training_idx]
    training_labels = [iris_labels[idx] for idx in training_idx]

    testing_set = [iris_data[idx] for idx in testing_idx]
    testing_labels = [iris_labels[idx] for idx in testing_idx]
    
    return (training_set, training_labels), (testing_set, testing_labels)
# run the designated classifier
def run_classifier(classifier, training, testing):
    classifier.fit(*training)

    expect = testing[1]
    predict = classifier.predict(testing[0])
    
    return expect, predict

# collect data on training size plateau
def simulate():
    # progress through range of testing data sizes
    nb_acc = []
    tree_acc = []
    training_fracs = [x/1000 for x in range(500, 850, 25)]

    for i in training_fracs:
        nb = naive_bayes.CategoricalNB()
        dt = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
        training, testing = sample_data(i)
        
        nb_expect, nb_predict = run_classifier(nb, training, testing)
        dt_expect, dt_predict = run_classifier(dt, training, testing)
        
        nb_acc.append(metrics.accuracy_score(nb_expect, nb_predict))
        tree_acc.append(metrics.accuracy_score(dt_expect, dt_predict))
        
    return nb_acc, tree_acc, training_fracs
        
nb_acc, tree_acc, fracs = simulate()
    
print(f"Naive Bayes accuracy @ 50% training: {nb_acc[0]}")
print(f"Decision Tree accuracy @ 50% training: {tree_acc[0]}")
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in
> get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    3079             try:
> -> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)    3081             except KeyError as err:
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 18
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 28     return nb_acc, tree_acc, training_fracs
> 29
> ---> 30 nb_acc, tree_acc, fracs = simulate()
> 31
> 32 print(f"Naive Bayes accuracy @ 50% training: {nb_acc[0]}")
>
> in simulate()
> 18         nb = naive_bayes.CategoricalNB()
> 19         dt = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
> ---> 20         training, testing = sample_data(i)
> 21
> 22         nb_expect, nb_predict = run_classifier(nb, training, testing)
>
> in sample_data(training_frac,
> iris_data, iris_labels)
> 11     assert(len(training_idx) + len(testing_idx) == len(iris_data))
> 12
> ---> 13     training_set = [iris_data[idx] for idx in training_idx]
> 14     training_labels = [iris_labels[idx] for idx in training_idx]
> 15
>
> in (.0)
> 11     assert(len(training_idx) + len(testing_idx) == len(iris_data))
> 12
> ---> 13     training_set = [iris_data[idx] for idx in training_idx]
> 14     training_labels = [iris_labels[idx] for idx in training_idx]
> 15
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
> **getitem**(self, key)    3022             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:    3023                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
> -> 3024             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)    3025             if is_integer(indexer):    3026                 indexer = [indexer]
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in
> get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    3080                 return
> self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)    3081             except KeyError
> as err:
> -> 3082                 raise KeyError(key) from err    3083     3084         if tolerance is not None:
>
> KeyError: 18

Comment: Where do you import iris dataset? it is not here, maybe you omitted that part where you initialize the `iris` and `iris_df`.

Answer (score 0):

Your assertion in `sample_data` fails so you get the `KeyError`,
For train test split just use:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
>>> X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
...     X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```